# melt in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

So I am working in R using `data table` and there are about 5000 observations. I have developed all these new grade variables into their own categories (ex. grade1, grade2, grade3,etc) and now I want to combine them into one variable called `Grade`. I have used the this command:

```
DT.m1 = melt(
   MathSummary,
   id.vars = c("Date", "Total.Events", "Unique.Events"),
   measure.vars = c("Gradeprek", "Grade1", "Grade2", "Grade3", "Grade4",
                                 "Grade5", "Grade6", "Grade7", "Grade8",
                                 "Algebra1", "Algebra2", "Geometry", "Precalculus"),
   value.factor=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE
)
```

However, when it results came, it gave me 65000 observations. Perhaps it may have created duplicates or something. Penny for your thoughts?

Comment: 13 measure.vars * 5000 = 65000 rows. That's what `melt` does.

Comment: What were you expecting as output?

Comment: I am expecting it to still have the same 5000 observations, but be aligned in one column called Grade

Comment: @MarkBornSuccessfulHarris - I can't see how that is possible. If you had a simplified example like `df <- data.frame(id=1:3, grade1=4:6, grade2=5:7, grade3=6:8)` how would your intended result look?

Comment: Do you want the grades as a group? As in `"87, 88, 57, 66"`? So that a single row has all of the grades as one element?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and supply a reproducible example with a few lines of your input data and show also the expected result. Thank you. Otherwise we will end up in guessing what you might being expecting.

Comment: Yes, for instance if there are dates ranging from January 1, 2015-June 30, 2016, how can i ensure that when I do combine my newly created grade variables into one variable called grade, that it will provide me with the aggregate total of all values under each day within that range correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is correct and you are just not understanding how melt works.  Melt turns your data into long-format and it looks like your code is working, as you have 13 variables and 5000 observations, so when turned into long format, you would get 13 * 5000 = 65000 observations.

However, in long format, a row should not be thought of as a single observation, instead it is a single measure instance. So in long format, you will notice that the melted data.table produced will look like.

Date Total.Events Unique.Events variable value

And so for each unique combination of your three measures, you will have thirteen rows, and each row will be a variable - value pair.